# uip homepage down? need uip documentation

Tags: ethernet

does anybody know what happend to http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page?
the complete sics.se server appears to be down

i desperately need the uip documentation...

Comment: seems like i need an openid to do that. will be done tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:  http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:zqLU33voPQYJ:www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page

Or this:  http://web.archive.org/web/20080730074245/http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this too: http://www.sics.se/~adam/old-uip/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation PDF can be found in one of my repositories: https://github.com/jsz/WiShield/blob/master/uip-1.0-documentation.pdf